# Php javascript associative array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, associative

```
<div class="main" action="then">
   <div class="sub">Rock</div>
   <div class="sub">Austin</div>
</div>
<div class="main" action="now">
  <div class="sub">Cena</div>
  <div class="sub">Bryan</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('.main').each(function({
    $(this).children('.sub') each({
     //push this.text into associative array
});}))
```

what i want is array to be something like this to send in php

```
$arr['then']=>array(rock,austin),
$arr['now']=>array(cena,bryan)
```

So that i can `foreach` through each array and get the names.

Comment: `action="then"` ? what's that?

Comment: Its just a attr nothng to worry about!

Comment: You can't define PHP variables in JavaScript (or jQuery for that matter), if that's what you're asking

Comment: Can you send JSON then parse it in PHP? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

So... something like this?

```
var result = {};
$(".main").each(function() {
    result[this.getAttribute("action")] = $.map($(".sub",this), function(node) {
        return node.firstChild.nodeValue;
    });
});
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36R2p/)

Answer (score 0):

To push `this.text` into associative array you can use the `push` method:

```
var array = [];
array.push(this.text);
```

Comment: No this will be something like
`$arr= array(rock,austin,cena,bryan)`

but i want arrays of specific `action` containing array of names

Answer (score 0):

```
var objToSend = {};
$('.main').each(function({
    var n = $(this).attr('action');
    objToSend[n] = [];
    $(this).children('.sub').each({
         objToSend[n].push($(this).text());
    });
});
var jsonToSend = JSON.stringify(objToSend);
```

Then `post` that string `jsonToSend` to your PHP.
To retrieve the string as an array in your PHP, use:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
```

Where `'json'` was the name of the data you sent through the post method (will be whatever name you assigned the `jsonToSend` string as) and the second argument converts it as a PHP array instead of an object. More information on `json_decode` here: [php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Gives error on console 
`cannot push to undefined` on line where push is applied

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. Should work now (that error was because `objToSend[n]` hadn't been defined as an array)